# Django REST conditional view get self

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST API views and I want to implement [conditional view processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/conditional-view-processing/)
Since I'm using class views, I need to use `@method_decorator` in order to use `@last_modified` decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.http import last_modified  
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):  
  def get_last_modified_time(*args, **kwargs):
      post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('id'))
      # >>> I need "self" here <<<
      return post.date

  @method_decorator(last_modified(last_modified_func=get_last_modified_time))  
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        .......
```

This code works fine but I need access to `self` in `get_last_modified_time()` method but there's no `self` anymore after adding `@method_decorator`.
And if I remove `@method_decorator`, I get an error in:

```
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py
line 102, in inner response = get_conditional_response()
```

since `self` is passed as the first argument instead of `request`.

Answer (score 0):

That was quite an opportunity to learn how decorators work.

```
def my_decorator(view_func):

    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        def get_last_modified_time(*_, **__):
            # here it is... now I can store attributes in self and access them later if needed  
            self.post = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('id'))
            return self.post.date

        decorator = method_decorator(condition(last_modified_func=get_last_modified_time))
        decorated_view_func = decorator(view_func)
        return decorated_view_func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper  

@my_decorator  
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
        .......
```